# Over-constrained general solution to wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, definition

[d'Alembert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) states that the general solution to the one-dimensional wave equation is $$ u(x,t) = f(x+ct) + g(x-ct).$$ for any well-behaved functions $f$ and $g$.  This is a well-known and popular result.  The 1D wave equation can be accompanied by two initial conditions and two boundary conditions, such as
\begin{align}
u(x,0) &= a(x) \\
u_t(x,0) &= b(x) \\
u(0,t) &= c(t) \\
u(1,t) &= d(t)
\end{align}
But given this much initial/boundary data, the "general solution" is over-constrained.  What is actually meant then when $ u(x,t) = f(x+ct) + g(x-ct)$ is referred to as a "general solution"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your conditions set up the requirement that 
$$f(x) + g(x) = a(x)$$
and
$$c (f'(x) - g'(x)) = b(x)$$
for $x \in (0,1)$, which basically completely determines $f$ and $g$ on the interval. More generally, you get the requirements that for all $t>0$,
$$f(ct) + g(-ct) = c(t)$$
and
$$f(1+ct) + g(1-ct) = d(t)$$
Now you can proceed inductively to sweep out the domains where $f$ and $g$ are defined.

For the zeroth, $f$ is defined on $0 \leq x \leq 1$, which from the first equation defines $g$ on $[-1,0]$, and similarly having $g$ defined on the unit interval defines $f$ on $[1,2]$ from the second equation.

Having $f$ defined on $[n,n+1]$ means $g$ is defined on $[-n-1,-n]$ using the first equation. Having $g$ defined on $[-n,1-n]$ means that $f$ is now defined on $[n+1,n+2]$ from the second equation. Rinse and repeat to define $f$ for $x> 0$ and $g$ for $x < 0$.

So rather than being overdetermined, I think you actually end up being underdetermined: you don't care what $f$ is for $x<0$, or $g$ for $x>1$. This actually makes sense: $f$ is a wave travelling in the negative direction, so the domain $[0,1]$ never "sees" what's travelling away from it. similarly, $g$ is a wave travelling in the positive direction.

Comment: Very interesting logic. But consider $a(x) = b(x) = c(t) = d(t) = 1$.  The last formula here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula) says that the solution would be $u(x,t) = 1 + t$, based on the initial conditions.  Perhaps derivation of the last formula requires an infinite domain?

Comment: Huh? 1+t doesn't satisfy your boundary conditions.

Comment: Correct.  But $1+t$ is the solution according to the last formula on the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula.  Does that particular formula assume something about the boundary conditions?

Comment: I think it assumes that they don't exist - it's for the equation on the whole line.

Comment: Thanks Ray.  You have given a very insightful answer.